# Change file extension in Windows 7 without making extensions visible in Explorer options

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, rename, file-extension

Occasionally I want to change the extension for a given file in Windows Explorer, e.g. rename `audio_only.mp4` to `audio_only.m4a`.

These valid possibilities are somehow unappealing:

- Show extensions in Explorer, this makes them editable.
- Use the shell command `rename`.

Is there a way to perform the renaming more quickly.

I assume this will need to add an entry in the contextual menu (right-click)?

Comment: it would take a whole 10 seconds to show all extensions. Make your changes, hide them again.

Comment: You could create a batch file that prompts you for the new extension and then renames a file you drag and dropped onto it.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I know, but how many times did I loose these 10s... and it is guaranteed to continue for years. At some point in time I wanted to solve this annoyance once for good.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question...

I found an open source shell extension working for multiple files at once.

[Change File Extension Shell Menu, by T800](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/OS-Enhancements/Change-File-Extension-Shell-Menu.shtml)

[image]

Comment: Nice software find, thanks, adding it to my collection.